# How can I build to repository sub project using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have Git repository in which one repository contains two project as below.

```
Repository 
   - Project A
   - Project B
```

My question is how can I build single project (**Project A**) through Jenkins.

When I use to git clone SSH URL in jenkinsfile it builds to whole repository but I want to build only **Project A**. So, could you please help me how can I do the same?
Please check below my jenkinsfile code:

```
 node {
      stage ('Build') {
        git url: 'git@github.com:abc/sample.git'
        withMaven {
          sh "mvn clean install"
        } 
      }    
   }
```

Comment: Welcome, please share your `Jenkinsfile` so we can further help you

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ, I have edit my question with ` jenkinsfile ` code

Comment: #1 Does Project A & Project B have its own pom.xml ? #2 are you using a parent pom in which you add your child modules: https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/a65ece2c96cf291bda0e48bfc76436c5#file-maven-parent-pom-xml ?

Comment: Yes @JRichardsz Project A & Project B have own pom.xml

Comment: #1 Are you using parent pom? #2 Are they independent projects? #3 Are they libraries or apps (web or api) ?

Comment: @JRichardsz #1. No I m not using parent pom. #2. Yes both are independent project. #3: One project is api and another is web

Comment: There are several options but one very easy would be to `sh "cd projectA"` before running Maven

Answer (score 0):

Is not a best practice to have several apps or libraries in one git repository. I advise you to use a git repository for each project. Also don't use spaces in sub projects name.

According to your comments, you will be able to compile your artifacts with one of the follow approaches:

### Parent pom

As a extremely summary, you could build several maven projects with one hit. In your case you must add one pom.xml at root.

```
my-git-repository
├── pom.xml
├── project-a
    ├── pom.xml
├── project-b
    ├── pom.xml
```

This new pom.xml must be something like this:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>acme.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>../project-a</module>
        <module>../project-b</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        ...
    </build>
</project>
```

Finally, at root execute `mvn clean package`. As you will see, all the registered project in `<modules>` will be compiled.

More details about maven submodules here:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

### dir step

You are using **node** in your script, so it's not a **declarative pipeline** in which jenkinsfile is used. You are using a **scripted pipeline**

No matter if you are using scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline, a step called **dir** is the solution

```
node {
  stage('Build') {
    git url: 'git@github.com:abc/sample.git'
    dir("Project-A") {
      withMaven {
        sh "mvn clean package"
      }
    }

    dir("Project-B") {
      withMaven {
        sh "mvn clean package"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More details about dir step and jenkins pipelines type here:

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/

  - search **dir: Change current directory** section
- [Jenkins scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484979/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-or-declarative-pipeline)

Comment: You are welcome. If it was useful, don't forget to click the arrow up!