# How to run stages in parallel but select agents on "lower level" of script?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a series of tests on multiple platforms (AIX, pi, macOS, Windows, Linux). Obviously that level can be executed in parallel.

```
    pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage ("Run Tests") {
          steps {
            parallel (
                     pi:{...}
                     aix: {...}
etc.
```

But the tests for "pi" can not run on any pi - I am testing against multiple versions of the software and need to select the specific platform per test, so the pi-Test (as well as aix) then goes on:

```
                     catchError(buildResult: "UNSTABLE", stageResult: "FAILURE") {
                       script{
                         def E="" // define some variables per platform
                         def res=""  
                         stage ("pi&&Version1") {
                           agent {
                             label "pi&&Version1"
                           }
                           script {
                             echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"            
                             ...intense code to test V1...
                           }
                         }
                         stage ("pi&&Version2") {
                           agent {
                             label "pi&&Version2"
                           }
                           script {
                             echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"            
                             ...intense code to test V2...
                           }
                         }
                       }
                     }
```

So each test on a platform needs an agent with a specific label which means that the agent is selected "deeper" within the code. And I haven't seen any examples doing this - maybe I read the wrong doc or did not understand it well enough - but I just can't find a way to structure my scripts in a way which would allow me doing this.

The script fails with
 `Invalid step "stage" used - not allowed in this context - The stage step cannot be used in Declarative Pipelines`

Any suggestions how to get this working will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing up declarative pipeline syntax and scripted pipeline syntax.
At first it looks like you are suing the old style [parallel syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) for your pipeline which has since been replaced with a more declarative [parallel syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) which will look something like the following:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage ("Run Tests") {
           parallel {
              stage('pi') {
                 ...
              }
              stage('aix') {
                 ...
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of which syntax you use, in the code block inside the parallel stage you are using scripted pipeline syntax (implied by the `script` directive) which allows you to use more advance code but prevents you from using declarative keywords like the `agent` directive.
So what you need to to is to convert the code in your stage into scripted syntax which means using `node` directives for your agent allocation.
It will look like:

```groovy
script{
   catchError(buildResult: "UNSTABLE", stageResult: "FAILURE") {
       def E="" // define some variables per platform
       def res=""
       stage ("pi&&Version1") {
           node("pi&&Version1") {
               echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"
               ...intense code to test V1...
           }
       }
       stage ("pi&&Version2") {
           node("pi&&Version2"){
               echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"
               ...intense code to test V2...
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The `script` directive (that implies a fallback to scripted pipeline syntax) is needed only once to wrap the script, and is not needed agin within the sub stages.

The full pipeline will look something like:

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
       stage ("Run Tests") {
           parallel {
               stage('pi') {
                   steps {
                      script {
                          catchError(buildResult: "UNSTABLE", stageResult: "FAILURE") {
                              def E = "" // define some variables per platform
                              def res = ""
                              stage("pi&&Version1") {
                                  node("pi&&Version1") {
                                      echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"
                                      ... intense code to test V1 ...
                                  }
                              }
                              ... other stages ...
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  stage('aix') {
                      ...
                  }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - most helpful! I must admit the difference between declarative/scripted pipelines (and the fact that some commands can appear in both, but with different syntax) is quite a hurdle for me as a n00b ;)  BTW, I had to inject a `steps{` after `stage("pi")` to get it working...

Comment: You are correct ill update my answer. Check out the [Syntax Compare](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare) from the official Jenkins site for the differences between both pipelines types, and also this useful [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484979/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-or-declarative-pipeline) for more info that might help to sort thing out.